# issue sticky navigation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am trying to build a sticky navigation with css and jquery i am using following code

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var navheight = $('.site-navigation').offset().top;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= navheight) {
        $('.site-navigation').addClass('fixed-site-navigation');
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < navheight) {
        $('.fixed-site-navigation').removeClass('fixed-site-navigation');
    }
});
```

when i scroll down, the second if() block doesn't execute (fixed-site-navigation class that has been added is not removing). could someone please help me to find the answer for this :)

Comment: you should probably use `else if` or `else` statement

Comment: @Elen That might be the right way of doing it, does that make a difference in the logic?

Comment: still getting same result

Comment: anyone knows better way of doing this? a better technique?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var navheight = $('.site-navigation').offset().top,
        toggle    = $(window).scrollTop() >= navheight;

    $('.site-navigation').toggleClass('fixed-site-navigation', toggle);
});
```

Comment: still getting the same result. the navigation remain fixed

Comment: @solom - quick [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DAGuK/1/) seems to be working for me (flickers a bit, but the class is added and removed)

Answer (score 0):

```
.fixed-site-navigation
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

should do the trick

Comment: i have already added this css rules to class "fixed-site-navigation".